# Почему не переносит на следующую строку?

Tags: php

имеется такая проблема, что у меня не переносит код на след.строку в PHP. Это система оповещения о входе:
Сам код `$text = "На сайте был выполнен вход! Логин: $login Пароль: $pass IP: $ip";`
Так вот, хочу, чтобы выводило так:

```
На сайте был выполнен вход! 
Логин: $login 
Пароль: $pass 
IP: $ip
```

Но проблема в том, что `echo '<br />';` и вообще связанное с `<br>` не помогает, выдает ошибку(

Comment: что за ошибку то?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
\n
```

Вместо

```
<br />
```

Comment: Тогда лог приходит в таком виде, почему-то _ вместо след.строки http://prntscr.com/nwcmaq

Comment: $text = "На сайте был выполнен вход! </br> Логин: $login </br> Пароль: $pass </br> IP: $ip";

https://pp.userapi.com/c855532/v855532680/5a85b/589MhlnUVrQ.jpg

Все работает.

Comment: тогда получаю такую ошибку http://prntscr.com/nwjp1d

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "На сайте был выполнен вход!\n Логин: $login \n Пароль: $pass \n IP: $ip";
```

Если это не поможет. Предоставьте пожалуйста больше кода, чтобы понимать что у Вас там происходит. Спасибо.

Comment: `$text = "На сайте был выполнен вход! \r\n Логин: $login \r\n Пароль: $pass \r\n IP: $ip";
$send = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chatid&parse_mode=html&text=$text");

header('Location: https://dribbble.com');`
Часть телеграмм бота нет смысла прикладывать, вот основное, с чем работаю

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее использовать

```
<br>
```

Но лучше, использовать список т.е.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>На сайте был выполнен вход!</li>
  <li>Логин:</li>
  <li>Пароль:</li>
  <li>IP:</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншоту указанному вами ([тык](http://prntscr.com/nwcmaq)) видно что лог куда-то отправляется. Если это так - советую вам прочитать документацию используемого ресурса по форматированию сообщений, но в 99% случаев один из данных способов должен сработать.

```
 - "text ".PHP_EOL." text"
 - "text <br> text"
 - "text <br/> text"
 - "text <br /> text"
 - "text \n text"
 - "text \r\n text"
 - "text \n\r text"
```

Comment: Совершенно верно, логи приходят в Телеграмм, но, увы, в документации я ничего не нашёл на этот случай :/ 
Используя `".PHP_EOL."`, я получаю лог такого вида http://prntscr.com/nwjgii , использую `\n, \r\n, \n\r`, это подчеркивание становится больше http://prntscr.com/nwjgqp

Comment: Вот ссылка - https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/reference#sendmessage. Если <br> не работает, попробуйте использовать <p> text </p> или markdowm-style (``` ... ```)

Comment: используя <p> text </p> получаю такое... http://prntscr.com/nwlsc5